# Set and find control by name

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

What I have is this and it's working fine:

```
if (direction.Equals("UR"))
{
    UR_Image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(String.Format("file:///{0}/../Family/" + name + "/Image/"+direction+".png", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())));
}
else if (direction.Equals("UL"))
{
    UL_Image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(String.Format("file:///{0}/../Family/" + name + "/Image/"+direction+".png", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())));
}
```

What I wish to do is below, written as pseudo code:

```
direction + _Image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(
    String.Format("file:///{0}/../Family/" + name + "/Image/"+direction+".png", 
    Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())));
```

How can I implement `direction + _Image` ?

Direction is a `string` and UL_Image and UR_Image are image views.

Comment: How about simply identifying your directions using integers, e.g. `"U"` being `0`, `UR` being `1`, `R` being `2`, etc.?

Comment: try storing your Images into a `Dictionary<string, Image>`, `direction` will be the key, corresponding to it is some `Image`, so it could be `yourDict[direction].Source = new BitmapImage...`, of course we should check for key existence first. Also consider using MVVM pattern. `Image` is just a control, we should not save it like as we save data.

Comment: Mario, the views are different, that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following approach.

**YourWindow.xaml**

```
<!-- named controls -->
<Image x:Name="ImageOne" />
<Image x:Name="ImageTheOther" />
```

**YourWindow.xaml.cs**

```
// get image control by name
var control = FindName(string.Format("Image{0}", direction)) as Image;
if (control == null)
    return;

// set bitmap once
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "image.png");
var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));

// assign
control.Source = bitmap;
```

Where `direction` is enumeration

```
public enum Direction
{
    One,
    TheOther
}
```